# Not Getting Response after sending request successfully in android using soap wsdl Webservices in Android

Tags: android, xml, soap, wsdl, xstream

I am stuck on the webservice parsing problem from some couple of days , This is my first time am using Soap wsdl webservice , I am using Xstream for parsing things , i send the request successfully but am not getting the proper response . the Webservice is like this .

Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://tempuri.org/service url">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
   <com:chkUniqeId soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <uid xsi:type="uniq:UniqueIdgenerationRequest" xmlns:uniq="http://service url/">
        <!--You may enter the following 3 items in any order-->
        <uid xsi:type="xsd:string">20150910034805007</uid>
        <module xsi:type="xsd:string">uniqueid</module>
        <type xsi:type="xsd:string">N</type>
     </uid>
  </com:chkUniqeId>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Response:

```
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-     ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
   <ns1:chkUniqeIdResponse SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/web service url">
     <return xsi:type="ns2:UniqueIdgenerationResponse" xmlns:ns2="http://Service url/">
        <flag xsi:type="xsd:string">N</flag>
        <status xsi:type="xsd:string">Unique ID (20150910034805007) Existing Already</status>
     </return>
  </ns1:chkUniqeIdResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Can anybody have idea how do I deal with this type of service in Android